# consider evaluate all third if second true

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

i'm to tired to think :)

is in java any simple solution to this ?

```
A B | =         XOR -> NO 
--------        AND -> NO
0 1 | 0         OR -> NO
0 0 | 0         
1 1 | 0
1 0 | 1
```

this came from

```
             condition 1       if condition 2    take condition 3
            evaluated to       evaluated to         to consider 
               true               true              

 return         a        &&       if(b)      &&              c           

                                  else  only a   


 // i can make it like this  
return (a && b) ? a && b && c : a; 
// then simplifying 
return b ? a && c : a;
```

but if a is statement i need make solution/compute & substitute on right side

**or maybe there's a simpler way to write this condition?**

*Does a && !b work? – bradimus*

*Maybe it's me -- but what are you asking? – Hovercraft Full Of Eels*

**example to consider:**

```
public boolean isRequestInQue(Request<User> requestToCheck, 
                              boolean checkCallerAlive) {
    int id = requestToCheck.getId();
    Request<User> requestInQue = _stateCallerRequestList.get(id);
    return requestInQue != null 
               ? checkCallerAlive 
               ? requestToCheck.equals(requestInQue) 
               && requestInQue.isCallerAlive() 
               : requestToCheck.equals(requestInQue) 
               : false;
}
```

*Ternary operator can be difficult to follow, especially if you are asking for help with the logic. Can you give an example using if statements? – dave*

```
if(requestInQue!=null)
   if(checkCallerAlive)
      if(requestToCheck.equals(requestInQue))
         if(requestInQue.isCallerAlive())
            return true;
   else if(requestToCheck.equals(requestInQue)
           return true;  
return false;
```

**finaly based on dave answer**

```
true && (!false || true) = true
true && (!true || true) = true
true && (!true || false) = false
true && (!false || false) = true

public boolean checkWithCifB(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    return a && (!b || c);
}
```

Comment: Does `a && !b` work?

Comment: Ternary operator can be difficult to follow, especially if you are asking for help with the logic.  Can you give an example using `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
return requestInQue != null && requestToCheck.equals(requestInQue) && 
       (!checkCallerActive || requestInQue.isCallerAlive());
```